# while using map(in a routes file, for a named route in rails4) this error ocurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
routes.rb
 TestApp::Application.routes.draw do 
  # get "secret" => "secret#new", :as => "secret"

  root:controller => "greetings", :action => "hello"
  map.secret '/secret/views', :controller => 'secret', action => 'new' 

end
```

This is hello.html.erb

```
<h1>Greetings#hello</h1>
<%= @message %> 
<p>Find me in app/views/greetings/hello.html.erb</p>
<% link_to "Secret Page", secret_path%>
```

> > Error: The link to secret page is not rendered
> >     Also, in rails4 when I tried to use map, it displayed map not recognized, route error
> >     undeclared variable, map. Why does this happen? Is there a a syntax error for |map|
> >     after the do in the first line, thanks, it may be a stupid question, appreciate
> >     the help!

Answer (score 0):

`map` is Rails 2 routing syntax, you don't need it anymore.